# Index of Substring Match

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a homework problem where I need to use Regular Expressions and LINQ to extract substring indices within a given array of strings and print them out. More specifically the question is this:

Write a correct, elegant and efficient extension method for a string that determines  (using Regular Expression(s) and LINQ) to determine, if the string contains  “ou” or “in” as a substrings and then returns the  beginning index of each substring and also returns true if any indexes exist and false if there are no valid indexes. NOTE: make sure you place a sentinel of -1 in the array of indexes.

This is the code I have written so far

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"ou", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"in", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string[] sData = new string[] {"Sour", "Candy", "apple",
            "Hotdog", "Jumping", "Pompadour", "Insane"};

        var selected2 = from strings in sData
                        let matches2 = regex2.Match(strings)
                        select matches2;
        var selected1 = from strings in sData
                        let matches = regex1.Match(strings)
                        select matches;

        foreach (var match in selected1)
        {
            WriteLine($"{match.Index}");
        }                
        WriteLine();
        foreach (var match in selected2)
        {
            WriteLine($"{match.Index}");
        }
        ReadKey(true);
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the foreach prints out an array of all zeros and where there are no matches and where there is a match it prints the index of where it's at in the string which is good but the question seems to want -1's instead of zeros where there are no matches. This makes sense of course because what if the match IS at zero? Also I have no clue on how to make it return true if the indices exist and false if not.  If anyone is good at LINQ I'd really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also I have no clue on how to make it return true if the indices exist
>   and false if not

You should look for `Match.Success`, which indicates whether the match is successful.

When it comes to the presentation (As you need `-1` when match unsuccessful), you could deal with conditional operator.

```
WriteLine($"{(match.Success? match.Index: -1)}");
```